# Android - change color of menu icon

Tags: android, menu, icons

How do I change the color of the menu icon ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you have achieved that menu icon in the first place.

If you have used a `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` then you can use `app:itemIconTint` in the xml or set it in the Java. See the following for more detail.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

If you are using an actionbar have you looked at `actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator();`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)

How are you getting that menu icon to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a customized menu icon:

Have a look here: [Icon Design Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)